# Do we need [customization] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is currently a [customization](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) tag which has 112 questions and a tag wiki excerpt of:

> Modifying the default state of an application to suit a user's
>   preferences or to address the unique requirements of a particular
>   objective.

Is it needed, or does having a tag for the spatial library used in that customization (e.g. [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy), [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis), [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers), [arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcobjects), etc) make it superfluous, and a candidate for burnination?

Also, ArcMap has a Customize Mode that is GUI rather than code driven, and I think that and equivalents in other software should be part of this discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that we need the [customization](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) tag and propose that we cease using it, and slowly burninate it.

We now have a [customize-mode](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customize-mode) tag, for the GUI driven Customize Mode of ArcGIS Desktop applications.

For code-driven customization there will already be tags like [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy), [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis), [leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaflet), [javascript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), etc for the language/library used to perform that customization.

---

Burnination of the [customization](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) tag was completed on 13 Dec 2021.